# Is there a Way to Return the Last Element of a Set in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

```
user-> (last '(First (Second (Last))))
-> (Second (Last))
```

I would typically assume this ^ would return just (Last). Why is this? And is there a way to return just (Last) or Last.

What about also for:

```
(defn function
 [input]              ;assume input = '(First (Second (Last)))

 (last input)

 )
```

Comment: Your `(defn function [input] (last input))` is equivalent to `(def function last)`.

Answer (score 6):

Strictly speaking, `(First (Second (Last)))` is not a Set, but a List. A Set is a collection of elements with no duplicates and ordering of the elements in not required.

If you look closely, it's a list of 2 elements. The first element is the symbol `First`, and the second element is itself a list: `(Second (Last))`

One of the foundational ideas of Clojure is the *sequence* abstraction: multiple collection data types allow you to take one element at time. You can call the function `seq` in collections such as HashMaps, Sets, Vectors and Lists.

In your case, you have a nested data collection: a List where one of the elements is a List, and so on...

For nested data structures you can use `tree-seq`, which will traverse your nested list one element at a time, going into nested collections where needed. [tree-seq](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/tree-seq) takes 2 or 3 arguments: an optional function to determine if an element is a branch (eg. contains other elements), the function to get the children of a branch, and the collection to traverse.

```clj
(tree-seq sequential? identity '(First (Second (Last))))

;; Note: Commas added for clarity
;; => ((First (Second (Last))), First, (Second (Last)), Second, (Last), Last)
```

From this, you can clearly extract the last element with `last`:

```clj
(last (tree-seq sequential? identity '(First (Second (Last)))))
;; => Last
```

Comment: Interesting. What about in regards to a function parameter? I re-edited my post to explain what I mean

Comment: Simply define the function to use `input` instead of the example value, like this: `(defn my-function [input] (last (tree-seq sequential? identity input)))`.