# Is it Possible to Drop the Last Element from a Set in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

```
(defn dropit
  [input]                         ;Assume input is '(This is (my input (and you (are awesome))))

  (drop-last input)              ;returns -> (This is)

  )
```

In the above function, drop-last does not do what you would assume it would do. Is there a way to drop just the last element from input so the return value is: (This is (my input (and you))

Is there a simple function to write for this?

Comment: Your input is a 3-element list containing `This`, `is` and the list `(my input (and you (are awesome)))` so `drop-last` has done the expected thing. Why is your input multiple nested lists?

Comment: You would need to recurse/navigate through each inner list until you find the last, inner-most list. What have you tried to do this though? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: I only want to drop (are awesome) from the end

Comment: @johnojacob Note the nesting. That isn't the "last" element by most definitions. Again, you're going to need to nagivate through the lists and find that inner-most list. You can use a helper function like `tree-seq` here to with navigating structures, or you can use `recur` and/or `loop` to navigate manually.

Comment: Okay, I would feel more comfortable recursing than using tree-seq. How would I go about this though? Any tips to get me started?

Comment: Is there really a major difference to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60610883/is-there-a-way-to-return-the-last-element-of-a-set-in-clojure ?

Answer (score 1):

Sets do not have an order guarantee in clojure unless you use `sorted-set`, so there may be unexpected results when using `drop-last` on a set. If you have a sorted set, you can drop last on it idempotently.

That said, the example data in your code's comments is not a set at all, it's a list, and the output you are seeing, given your input, is expected since there are three elements in that list, the last being a list itself, with its own elements:

```
first => "This"
second => "is"
last => ("my" "input" ("and" "you" ("are" "awesome")))
```

Dropping last here should yield `(This is)`, which is what you indicated is occurring.

If you want to drop the inner list `'("are" "awesome")` you could follow some of the traversal advice being given to you in the comments. Also, if you don't mind making your input a vector, you can do some associative operations on it, shooting from the hip, something like:

```
(assoc 
  input 
  (- (count input) 1)
  (->> input
    (take-last 1)
    first
    (drop-last 1)))
```